# hibernate throws unexpected token: ( near line 1 exception for a query(that includes subqueries) that works with sql

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a query which fetches name from table C for every id from table C which is also present in table D.

```
select
   status,
   name 
from
   (
      select
         id,
         name 
      from
         A,
         (
            select
               name,
               age 
            from
               B,
               (
                  select
                     p_id,
                     name 
                  from
                     C
               )
               c 
            where
               c.p_id = B.p_id
         )
         b 
      where
         b.age = A.age
   )
   a,
   D 
where
   D.id = a.id 
group by
   status,
   name;


Table FIELDS: SAY,
A- id,age
B - p_id,age
C-p_id,name
D-id,status
```

This works very fine in sql. But as I am using this in a java application, I am using hibernate for ORM. This fails in hibernate.

I throws an HibernateQuerySyntax exception:
unexpected token: ( near line 1, column .....
This is at this line: "select status,name from (select".

Does hibernate not support selecting columns thorugh subqueries?
Any help please?
what should I do?
I have tried with joins, but as there lot of records(>4million) in tables, it takes more than 20 seconds for execution. So I have tried with subqueries.

(lets assume every age is associated to one name).

Answer (score 0):

I realised the mistake. I was using createQuery instead of createSQLQuery.